# Call Hierarchy Eclipse feature in Vim?

Tags: c++, eclipse, vim

I am considering migrating from eclipse to vim for c++ development- I've recently "rediscovered" Vim, and finally went beyond the basics. I'm loving it, but there are still a few features that I use constantly in Eclipse that I'd also like to see in Vim.

One of them is call hierarchy. It's extremely helpful to know where a particular function/method is called throughout a project, and having an overview at a glance. Is there a similar plugin for that in Vim? Perhaps a combination of plugins/commands that are equivalent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149558/recommended-vim-plugins-for-c-coding

A combination of the cscope and taglist plugins (linked from above) should give you what you want. Possibly [cctree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2368). All of these have problems with templates, however.

Also check out [eclim](http://eclim.org/)

Comment: Detailed steps to find one level of the call hierarchy with cscope: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31501431/895245

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse has a built-in C++ parser that runs in the background and fully parses and semantically analyzes C++ code. This is what allows it to provide code completion, call hierarchy, refactoring and similar features.

I'm not aware of anything like that being available for vim. If someone knows something like that, I would be interested too.